# DBT (Data Build Tools) - Create CI/CD pipeline in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, dbt, cicd, fishtown-analytics

I am working on a project that uses DBT by Fishtown Analytics for ELT processing. I am trying to create a CI/CD pipeline in Azure DevOps to automate the build release process, but I am unable to find a suitable documentation around it. The code has been integrated in DevOps Repos, now I need a reference to start with building the CI/CD pipelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our team uses ADO Pipelines, [here’s our doc](https://dbt-msft.github.io/dbt-msft-docs/docs/ado_pipelines_example) on how we do it!

To make this example work, you will need 3+ files:

#### 1. [`profiles.yml`](https://github.com/dbt-msft/ado_pipelines_example/blob/main/build/profiles.yml).

If you look at this file, you'll see usage of dbt-jinja's `env_var` macro. This lets you make ADO Pipeline secret variables for your database credentials, and make them available to dbt.

#### 2. [`step_template.yml`](https://github.com/dbt-msft/ado_pipelines_example/blob/main/build/step_template.yml)

This file is a recipe of deployment steps that are used when deploying to different environments. The beauty of the dbt CLI is that the same steps are used when:

- doing our integration tests (gatekeeper), and
- deploying to our production and staging/UAT environments.
  So this `step_template.yml` lets each pipeline re-use the same steps. It's worth noting here that because we are using the `AzureCLI@2` task because it will auto-authenticate to Azure for us. If you're not using Azure, you'll need to:
- add Pipeline secrets for username and password to the db, and
- use the `Bash@3` task

#### 3. [`gatekeeper.yml`](https://github.com/dbt-msft/ado_pipelines_example/blob/main/build/gatekeeper.yml) and [`prod.yml`](https://github.com/dbt-msft/ado_pipelines_example/blob/main/build/prod.yml)

These are the actual pipelines. If you look, they are identical except for:

- **the variables** they deploy to different databases), and
- **the trigger** changes to which branch will trigger this pipeline?
- **the schedule** should this run even if there are no new commits to the branch? Yes, if production because we want the data to stay up-to-date for our users.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Can you also help me with brief description of what each file is meant for, the ones present under ado_pipelines_example/build/.

Comment: just added more context!

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. One thing that I have observed is - after setting up profiles.yml, if I make any updates to this file, say changing the authentication, the build pipeline always picks the old version of this file. Another error that it is giving is :  dbt_project.yml file [ERROR not found]

Comment: for the first error, try changing the trigger for one of the pipelines to be `*`, so that it runs for every commit on every branch?

Comment: resolved the first error, however still stuck with the issue  while running the command -dbt debug --profiles-dir $(location) --  dbt_project.yml file [ERROR not found]. Both  dbt_project.yml and profiles.yml are present at the exact same location

Comment: @user961 wish I could be more helpful here but my only advice is to add steps to print out your current working directory and the files in them. That’ll help you debug I bet

Comment: Thanks for your help. I resolved this error by changing the working directory for the Azure CLI task (so that it is able to locate the dbt_project.yml file) as                     
 - task: AzureCLI@2
    displayName: 'dbt debug'
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: XXXX
      ScriptType: bash
      scriptLocation: inlineScript
      workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
      inlineScript: |
        dbt --version
        dbt debug --profiles-dir $(location)